# set UIView's Content to CAlyer's Contents in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, calayer

I am trying to add view's content to LAyer's content, IS it possible?

```
v1=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 30)];
        v1.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
        UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(05, 05, 20, 20)];
        lbl.text=@"ABC";
        [v1 addSubview:lbl];

       CALayer *iconImageLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
    iconImageLayer.contents=?????? //Try to add view
```

**Help me solve this**

**Thank you,**

Answer (score 0):

Use the `layer` property of `UIView`.

`CALayer *iconImageLayer = v1.layer`

or just simply use `v1.layer` wherever you would have used `iconImageLayer`.